# AngularJS+ Firebase can't get data preloaded on route change

Tags: angularjs, firebase

```
 var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['firebase'])
 .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function
     ($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
 {

 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
 .when('/test', {
    templateUrl: '/views/test.html',
    controller: testCrtl,
    resolve:
    {
        firedata: function($q,angularFire){
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        var ref = new Firebase('https://shadowfax.firebaseio.com/items');
        ref.on('value', function(result){
            deffered.resolve(result.val());
        });

        return deffered.promise;
        }

    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
  // $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
  }]);


angular.module('testApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$rootScope', function ($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope) {

    $scope.load = function(){ return false;}
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
    $scope.load = function(){ return true;}

    });


}]);

 testApp.controller('TestCtrl',['$scope','$timeout','Fire','firedata','testCrtl']);

 var testCrtl = function ($scope,$timeout,Fire,firedata) {

            $scope.items=firedata;

 };
```

In the code above, why is the value of `$scope.items=firedata;` null? Please explain how can I perform a Google-like route change to preload data for the controller? This example works like John Lindquist explains, but when I use Firebase's native JS library, I can't get the data preloaded.

Also, using the Firebase angularFire library doesn't help, because it uses $scope as a parameter and it's not possible to pass $scope to the resolve function.

Comment: Looks to me like 'TestCtrl' is never loaded, since you spelled it 'TestCrtl' in your router. Or is this just a typo in your question, not your code?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `angularFireCollection` to preload data:

```js
.when('/test', {
  templateUrl: '/views/test.html',
  controller: testCrtl,
  resolve: {
    firedata: function(angularFireCollection){
      return angularFireCollection('https://shadowfax.firebaseio.com/items');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: angularFireCollection('https://shadowfax.firebaseio.com/items/-Iz3_MPc3Qe1EbHFNxQL')

If I use this link to get Item by ID, firedata becomes not an Object like {"name":"main","color":"blue"} why? How can I get an JSONObject by ID using angularFireCollection ?

Comment: Do you need to get a specific object? If you need to get many of them, create the collection at `/items`, then obtain the individual items via the returned collection.

If not, then I'm afraid the easiest way is to fetch the item directly using the Firebase API and bypassing angularFire altogether. You can use `ref.once('value')` to retrieve a value like you did in your code snippet.

I'd encourage filing an issue on the angularFire Github repo to add this functionality!